# the function works only the second time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, anko

I long clicked the task , and it disappears, I go to another screen and come back and see this task, after that I long  click it again and only after that the task is completed(state = 1),
debugger says code is executed

```
override fun onLongClick(view: View, position: Int) {
    val aims = aimsList!![position]
    aimsList!!.removeAt(position)
    adapter!!.notifyItemRemoved(position)
    doAsync {
        aims.state = 1 //state "1" is completed task, state"0" is uncompleted 
        AimsDataBase.getINSTANCE(context!!).daoAccess().updateAim(aims)`

        uiThread {
            Toast.makeText(context!!, "completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but could "aimsList" get repopulated from the database before the "updateAim()" has completed (somewhere outside the provided code), and thus it shows up back on the UI? Putting a breakpoint on updates to the adapter should catch whoever is putting it back on the list.